# Groups of orders $7!$ and $\frac{7!}{2}$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

In our research, we need to know that whether every group $G$ of order $2520 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7=\frac{7!}{2}$ or $5040 = 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7=7!$ has a proper subgroup non-isomorphic to the following groups
\begin{gather*}
C_1,\;
 C_2,\;   C_2\times C_2,\; C_2\times C_2\times C_2,\; C_2\times C_2\times C_2\times C_2,
  \\
 C_3,\; C_3\times C_3,\;
 C_4,\;
   C_5,\;
   S_3,\;
    C_7,\;
   C_4\times C_2 ,\; D_8,\; Q_8
\end{gather*}
(i.e., all groups of orders $\leq 9$ except $C_6$, $C_8$, $C_9$, together with $C_2\times C_2\times C_2\times C_2$).

Note that

1. the above list of groups contains at least a $p$-group, for all existing primes $p$ (here), up to their powers.
2. if $G$ is nilpotent, then it is true (because $G$ would contain the subgroup $C_{p_1p_2}$ for all distinct prime divisors $p_1$ and $p_2$ of $|G|$).
3. from [Groups of order $2520$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643757/groups-of-order-2520) it seems the answer is positive for $\lvert G\rvert=2520$.

Comment: Have you tried an argument along similar lines as my MSE answer?

Comment: If not, then a Sylow $3$-subgroup would either be normal, or self-normalizing, in which case there would be a normal $3$-complement by Burnside's Transfer Theorem, and the result follows easily in both cases.

Comment: @ verret- Not yet.

Comment: @ Derek Holt - Many thanks.

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand I think the expectation is that you've made some reasonable attempts to solve the question yourself before posting here...

Comment: @ verret- I read it, but since I'm not a specialist in group theory, I'm not familiar with many concepts in your answer.